# How can I remove the wrapper div or change its type from div to span within ember-from-for?

Tags: javascript, forms, ember.js, form-for, bulma

I am using bulma.io and for using its style classes for a selectbox it requires the following code.

```
<div class="field">
  <label class="label">Subject</label>
  <p class="control">
    <span class="select">
      <select>
        <option>Select dropdown</option>
        <option>With options</option>
      </select>
    </span>
  </p>
</div>
```

which requires a span instead of div for wrapping the (label and select tag).

I've tried to use `tagName="span"` but the generated code was like that [link](https://ibb.co/djBZvk)

here is my code

```
 <div class="field">
  <p class="control">
    {{f.select-field "countries"
      countries
      optionValuePath="value"
      optionLabelPath="text"
      labelClasses="label"
      label="Location"
      required=true
      tagName="span"
    }}
  </p>
 </div>
```

which generated a span wrapping the div .. not converting the div to span
`<span><div><label><select></div></span>`

Answer (score 1):

If you include select into a component, the component is wrapped with span:

component/my-select.js : 
    import Ember from 'ember';

```
export default Ember.Component.extend({
  tagName: 'span',
  classNames: ['select']
});
```

templates/components/my-select.hbs :

```
<select>
   <option>Select dropdown</option>
   <option>With options</option>
</select>>
```

myPage.hbs :

```
<div class="field">
 <p class="control">
  {{my-select}}
 </p>
</div>
```

here is the [twiddle](https://ember-twiddle.com/70855a15386a3d8b6cf82f0a1ec58f16?openFiles=templates.components.my-select.hbs%2Ctemplates.components.my-select.hbs)

Comment: I am using "ember-form-for", and I want to customize it, not to create my own component.